# Android - How to read txt file in JAVA

Tags: java, android, arabic

Please Will some one help me out i am trying to read an Arabic .txt file and it always give me the Arabic word like this "????? ???"

```
private String ReadArabic() {

    String words="";
    try {
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("arabwords.txt");

        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        words = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        words = words.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exceptions here
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: Is the file actually UTF8?

Comment: yes the file is UTF8

Comment: Did you check the byte values to make sure it isn't just a font issue (the font may not know how to display arabic characters)

Comment: i already have the fonts up and running                                                  type1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arabic.ttf");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using: "cp864" instead of "UTF-8"

Comment: :) glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

> Its possible that your console is not set to
>   properly display UTF-8 characters.

The configuration of that depends
on the IDE. You might need to configure the same there.

Answer (score 0):

it worked by using **"cp1256"**
Thanks Evey one

```
private String ReadArabic() {

    String words="";
    try {
        InputStream stream = getAssets().open("arabwords.txt");

        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        words = new String(buffer, "cp1256");
        words = words.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exceptions here
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: you might want to be more explicit on where you inserted `cp1256` so that other people who come to this question can solve it as well